# What is Causing my In-App Review Code To Not Display (Android)?

Tags: java, android, review

This is my first App - It is live in the Google Play Store. However, my in-app review is not displaying. I followed the instructions from the Google Android Developers Guide, but I need some assistance in spotting what I did wrong.

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#java

**Step #1:**

I created 2 variables outside of onCreate:

```
private ReviewManager manager;
private ReviewInfo reviewInfo;
```

**Step #2**

I created an activate review info method:

```
private void activateReviewInfo() {

        manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
        Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();

        request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
               reviewInfo = task.getResult();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "activateReviewInfo: There is an error at 28979");
            }
        });
    }
```

**Step #3**

Next I created a start review flow method:

```
private void startReviewFlow() {

        if(reviewInfo != null) {

            Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo);
            flow.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

            });
        } else {
          
            Log.d(TAG, "29005 -->  review info == null!");
        }
    }
```

The instructions here said to leave the task empty, unless I misunderstood what was being said.

**Step #4**

Method to show the request - to call the ratings flow:

```
private void showRatingsRequest() {

        if(games_won == 5 || games_won == 15 || games_won == 25) {

            Log.d(TAG, Start Review Flow!");

            startReviewFlow();
        }
    }
```

I call the showRatingRequest() method after the player wins the game, sample code below:

```
private void endGame(Animation bottomAnimation) {

   // A lot of code to display game's score, time, moves after the game is won
   // play win game music
   
   showRatingsRequest();
}
```

The endGame() method displays an overlay which displays the player's score, time, number of moves, a replay game button and a new game button.

I know the showRatingsRequest() is being Called because I get the "Start Review Flow!" message in the LogCat. However, I do not get the overlay display for the ratings.

I've watched a few videos on this, one called out the application ID as a potential issue during testing, but since my app is live the applicationID in the build.gradle is populated.

Also - I did add the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0'
}
```

Now, my app is written with Java, so I ***did not add*** the Kotlin dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.0'
```

The implementation seems rather simple, but obviously I did something wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated, I can't grow the app if I can't get people to rate it.

I forgot one thing:

In onCreate I have this code:

activateReviewInfo();

Comment: When do you call `activateReviewInfo`? The `ReviewInfo` you get there can expire -> "Note: The ReviewInfo object is only valid for a limited amount of time. Your app should request a ReviewInfo object ahead of time (pre-cache) but only once you are certain that your app will launch the in-app review flow."

Comment: I made an edit - in onCreate I have activateReviewInfo() ... however to your point maybe this should not be called every tine the app is created.

Comment: Did you try their [testing instructions](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test)? They also have a troubleshooting guide there of common reasons the review UI might not show

Comment: Yes, I reviewed all of those testing instructions. None of the troubleshooting issues seem applicable to my situation. Thanks.